# Make foreign key to ApplicationUser in auxiliary table (EntityFramework Identity)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have my **ApplicationUser** model defined like so:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual UserProfileInfo UserProfileInfo { get; set; }
}
```

With **UserProfileInfo** being an auxiliary table containing extra user data, defined as such:

```
public class UserProfileInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SuperiorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SuperiorId")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Superior { get; set; }
}
```

Each user has one or more people who are superior to them, in a business hierarchy. However, attempting to do a migration results in the following error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'Superior' on type 'Project.Models.UserProfileInfo' is not valid. The foreign key name 'SuperiorId' was not found on the dependent type 'Project.Models.ApplicationUser'.

How can I make a foreign key reference to **ApplicationUser** in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it the other way around, the ID is the foreignkey of the navigational property:

```
public class UserProfileInfo
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("Superior")]
   public string SuperiorId { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Superior { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I was confused on exactly how the foreign key/navigation properties were established.